# c++ mpi non-blocking vs blocking send

Tags: c++, mpi

```
if(rank==0) {
   for(ei=1;ei<NCORES;ei++) {
      buf=&bufsnd[displs[ei]];
      rc=MPI_Send (buf,lenrec,MPI_BYTE,ei,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //rc=MPI_Isend(buf,lenrec,MPI_BYTE,ei,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
}
if(rank!=0)
   rc=MPI_Recv (bufrec,lenrec,MPI_BYTE,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
```

Hi everybody, I am using the instructions above to dispatch data to be worked on by different processes. Process 0 has the data and sends them to all other processes. After the send, it starts working on its own data portion. I have tried both the Send and the Isend and, curiously, the execution is much faster with the Send, while I was expecting to be faster with the Isend, as in this case the master doesn't wait the completion of the ith send before executing the (i+1)th send, and all send should happen simultaneously. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Although non-blocking operations are often advertised as concurrent to the user program, most MPI libraries are single-threaded and can only progress the operations while inside some MPI call. This is usually done for performance reasons as true async progression increases the latency. Therefore, with `MPI_Isend`, you should periodically call `MPI_Test` on the non-blocking send request to allow the library to progress it. But notice also that your code is a reimplementation of `MPI_Scatterv`.

Comment: The code looks like a reimplementation of the Scatter function, because the data structures were indeed used for Scatter, as I was expecting that giving the full control to Mpi would result in an optimsed code (which was not the case).
Regarding your suggestion, I have added a cycle of MPI_test, one for each MPI_Isend. As a result, the speed now equals the MPI_Send program version. Why and how this happens, I have to be honest with you, remains a complete mistery to me.

Comment: MPI implementations are allowed to postpone the progression of non-blocking operations like `MPI_Isend` until the matching `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test` is called. I don't see the wait/test operation in your original code. If you never call `MPI_Wait`/`MPI_Test` on a non-blocking request, the operation might never get progressed.